# iOS NavigationCotroller pushViewController when init with UITabBarViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My main viewController A has a `UITabbarViewController` which has 5 tabs.

- On viewcontroller A, I set `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]` for some purpose of my app.
- On viewController at tab 2, I have a table view, I want when I select a row of table, I will present a viewController B (with also has navigationBar and tabbar)

  - I tried `[self.navigationController pushViewCOntroller:B animated:YES]` but it's not workking. I think because of setting hidden for navigationBar
  - I also tried `[self presentModalViewController:B]`, it worked but on viewcontroller B, it showed full screen (navigationBar and tabbar disappeard)

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is viewControllerA the viewController of tab 1? If not, what do you mean by "viewControllerA _has a_ UITabbarViewController"?

Comment: Setting the navigation bar to hidden would have no effect on whether a push works or not. Is the view controller in tab 2 embedded in its own navigation controller? When you say it's not working, what do you mean by that? Do you get an error message? Does it just do nothing?

Comment: Ah let I describe more clearly. I have main controller A, I add uitabbarcontroller to it. My tabbar has another 5 viewcontroller for 5 tabs. On viewcontroller at tab 2, I want to navigate into viewcontroller B. @He Was

Comment: @rdelmar I think you right, on the view controller at tab 2 not embedded in its own navigation controller (I NSLog and found that this navigationcontroller is NULL). But can you show me how to I embedded navigation controller into it, viewcotroller at tab2 just be added into uitabbarcontroller, and I have no way to embedded navigationcotroller into it. About it not working, I mean it does nothing when click on it to navigate into another viewcontroller

Comment: 1 / How are you adding the 'uitabbarcontroller' to the main controller A? 2 / Is tab2->ViewControllerB the only place you want a navigationController navBar?

Comment: @HeWas: 1/I init uitabbarcontroller and use its method setViewControllers to add 5 viewcontroller into 5 tabs, then I set [mainViewController.view addSubView: uitabbarviewcontroller.view]. 2/Maybe Not only at tab2, on others tab I also want to navigate into other viewController, too

Comment: @pf2707 ... see my updated answer with code example. Is the tabBarController the first screen of you app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
                         tabBarController
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |-->Item1ViewController
                                    |
                                    |-->NavController->Item2ViewController->push->VCB
                                    |
                                    |-->Item3ViewController
                                    |
```

Just make sure that tabBarController is not already enclosed in a NavigationController, this would cause confusion.

You can optionally show/hide the nav bar on Item2ViewController and VCB by setting their respective properties.

If using the storyboard, you can embed Item2ViewController in NavContoller after setting up the tabBarController by using the menu item "embed in...".

If in code you can do this sort of thing:

```
    UIViewController* vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController* vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController* vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController* vc4 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController* vc5 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* navC = 
           [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
    NSArray* viewControllers  = @[vc1,navC,vc3,vc4,vc5];
    UITabBarController* tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabC.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    [self presentViewController:tabC animated:YES completion:nil];

        //  don't do this:
    //  [self.view addSubview:tabC.view];
```

(The 'presenting' bit is debatable, it really depends on the rest of your app structure).

Comment: Thanks so much, I really did it. :) Your suggestion is reasonable, and quite simple, but I don't realize it sooner. Can I ask you more question, why you said that don't do [self.view addsubview:tabC.view], Is it wrong?

Comment: @pf2707 `[self.view addsubview:tabC.view]` may result in a crash (the tabView is going to want to send messages to it's controller which may no longer exist as you haven't placed it in any hierarchy). Take a look at [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1). Instead of 'presenting', if your tabBarController provides the root view for your app, you can just set it in your App Delegate as the `self.window.rootViewController`.